# Appwrite function not returning any value

Tags: node.js, appwrite

I'm trying to get the list of documents with the Appwrite function, unfortunately, I can't get any value.

```
const sdk = require("node-appwrite");

module.exports = async function (req, res) {
  const client = new sdk.Client();

  // You can remove services you don't use
  const database = new sdk.Databases(client);

  if (
    !req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT"] ||
    !req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY"]
  ) {
    console.warn(
      "Environment variables are not set. Function cannot use Appwrite SDK."
    );
  } else {
    client
      .setEndpoint(req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT"])
      .setProject(req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_PROJECT_ID"])
      .setKey(req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY"])
      .setSelfSigned(true);
  }

  const DbCollection = "64bb1ee4200b221e0675";

  const usersCollection = "64bb1f396ed41ad9c1d8";
  const prayerPartnerCollection = "6545e03a11aa6b5ba77a";
  const prayerPartnerHistoryCollection = "6545e4ba5bcad02198c0";
  const notificationCollection = "654cd8010d7f67c0d238";

  const promise = database.listDocuments(DbCollection, usersCollection);

  promise.then(
    function (response) {
      res.json({
        myResponse: response,
      });
    },
     (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.json({
        myError: error,
        endPoint: req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT"],
        projectId: req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_PROJECT_ID"],
        functionApi: req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY"],
      });
    }
  );
};
```

over the past 7hrs, I have been reading appwrite documentation on how to make this code work, but nothing I do seems to work, i have to try PHP runtime yet, nothing its working.

please what am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: any response at all?

Comment: I dont even understand, but i followed thier instruction here 
https://appwrite.io/docs/references/cloud/server-nodejs/databases#listDocuments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that the function is returning before the promise is resolved. I recommend not using `promise.then`. Instead, use async await.

So, this block:

```js
  const promise = database.listDocuments(DbCollection, usersCollection);

  promise.then(
    function (response) {
      res.json({
        myResponse: response,
      });
    },
     (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.json({
        myError: error,
        endPoint: req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT"],
        projectId: req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_PROJECT_ID"],
        functionApi: req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY"],
      });
    }
  );
```

would be:

```js
  try {
    const response = await database.listDocuments(DbCollection, usersCollection);

    return res.json({
      myResponse: response,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.toString());
    return res.json({
      myError: error.toString(),
      endPoint: req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT"],
      projectId: req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_PROJECT_ID"],
      functionApi: req.variables["APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY"],
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply @StevenNguyen, i did just you did, now i can see the error outputted, this is what i'm getting now in the Log 

~Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80~

Comment: Are you using localhost for the function endpoint? If so, that won't work because the function runtime container will connect to itself, but it needs to connect to Appwrite. You can try using your LAN IP instead of localhost, but you may need to set the domain environment variables in your Appwrite .env file to the IP address.

Comment: Thanks, @StevenNguyen, would just move everything to Appwrite Cloud now to test everything. will get you feedback later.
thanks man, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried almost every version of the endpoint.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/77557934/10749730 
Did you solve this problem? @StevenNguyen where exactly would I edit this? What .env file do you mean?